# Is it possible to properly type hint the filterM function in Python?

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, type-hinting

I'm currently self-studying functional programming by writing a monad library in python. And I'm having trouble with type hinting. So for example, there is a function filterM in Haskell with signature

```
filterM :: (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
```

Ideally, if python can pattern match "subtypes" of a TypeVar by putting a bracket after it, then I should be able to do it with something like this:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
M = TypeVar('M', bound=Monad)
def filterM(filter_func: Callable[[T], M[bool]], iterable: list[T]) -> M[list[T]]
```

But it seems that the above syntax wouldn't work. In fact, it seems like there is no way to "extract" the type of monad I pass in at all. Say I pass in a `Callable[[int], Maybe[bool]]`, the best I achieved was to take the whole `Maybe[bool]` as a single TypeVar. Then there is no way to convert it to the correct output type `Maybe[list[int]]`.

Comment: One of the biggest advantages of Haskell compared to other programming languages is how powerful its type system is. It shouldn't be a surprise if things that are easy in its type system are just flat-out impossible in other languages' type systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Currently, what you want cannot be done.](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548) You'll have to make a plan that doesn't require it.